# How to put a list of images in a fixed div

Tags: javascript, html, css, fixed

I've got a lateral fixed div (like a menu bar) and I am trying to figure out how i could put images in there, in a table-like view (for example 3 columns and X rows) knowing that those images are dynamically generated.

To be more specific, I would have 10 images to put in there. I can put them there just in html, but then javascript is gonna display or not certain images depending on various factors (mostly user privilegies), and so I would like those images to re-order automatically.

I'm more a JS than a CSS fan so I would place the images in fixed and use a script to handle their top and left properties, but I am sure there is some way of doing this with css (not css3, I am trying to do some retro-compatibility) or any other simpler way.

Thanks a lot

Comment: For security: Hiding/showing elements based on user privileges should ideally be not done on the client side. Only the stuff a user has access to, should reach the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need.
http://jsfiddle.net/x6zfW/10/

Please confirm.

HTML:

```
<div id="ui_myMenu">
            <div id ="ui_ui_myMenuTitle">HELLO TITLE</div>
            <img id="ui_image1" class="ui_menuIcons" src ="http://www.designworks.co.nz/uploads/images/case-studies/nz-post/post_button.jpg"/>
            <img id="ui_image2" class="ui_menuIcons" src="http://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/24/77/15/400_F_24771516_GheG3ehk2o3T6mJJkFy9k2siYoMrVigc.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #ui_myMenu{
position: fixed;
    bottom: 15%;
    width: 575px;
    height: 426px;
    left: 2%;
    top:2%;
    background:url('http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/abstract-background.jpg') left top no-repeat;
}
#ui_myMenuTitle{
    margin-left: 16%;
    margin-top: 4.8%;
    font-size: 380%;
}
.ui_menuIcons{
    float: left;
    width : 5%;
    height : 7%;
}
```

Comment: You can make further edits to this so that it suits you like you want.

Comment: That seems to work well, I'm going to try it on the project and I confirm you (I hope^^)

Comment: It works well, only problem is when I want to add padding to the myMenu div, it moves itself instead of replacing its content

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want the background image to begin somewhat from below or just the icons moved down ?

Comment: my bad, it works with the top property defined ( i wanted just the icons to move down). Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just one more thing, you changed the image I put in background with a background  image css property but that doesnt stretch the background image to the div anymore. How can I do that ?

Comment: Did my suggestion not do exactly that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) ...

If not, wrap the icons and position their container http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HAggq/

Comment: Well i know that plugin but I think that would be useful for more complicated situations, with a lot of rectangular divs and everything, all I want is a grid of a few elements replacing themselves when some of them get hidden or get display:none. That would be made automatically with floating divs I guess, but the point is that I don't know if I could use them in a fixed parent div.

Comment: What is fixed about the div? Can you give examples - for example a jsfiddle with lorempixel

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x6zfW/5/
I put random images but as you see, all of them get stacked up. I want them to display in a grid into the fixed div and if possible to make them rearrange when one gets display none
Thanks again

Comment: Remove position fixed on the icon css

Comment: But then the images go on the top of the ui_menuBackgroundImage instead of being on it

Comment: That's why i want to ask what you really want to do?

1. Do you want to have images like you asked in the question above ?
2. Or you want images like your jsfiddle example ?

Comment: i want images like I asked, displayed like a grid on my background image